# Show that the following sequence of functions converge uniformly to exp(x)

Tags: real-analysis

Show that the sequence of functions
$f_n=(1+(exp(1/n)-1)x)^n$ converge uniformly to $exp(x)$ on [0,1].
I tried to differentiate the function to find maximum value but I got stuck .
How should I tackle this problem.
Any hints?

Comment: You might want to see whether you can use $g_n(x)=\left(1+\frac{x}{n}\right)^n$ as an intermediate step

Answer (score 0):

My attempt, let $g_{n}=nx(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)$ then $f_{n}=(1+\frac{g_{n}}{n})^{n}$ if you can prove that $g_{n}\rightarrow x$ then $f_{n}\rightarrow e^{x}$ we want $n(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\rightarrow 1$ now $u=(e^{\frac{1}{n}}-1)\Rightarrow  $ the limit is the same as $\lim \frac{u}{ln(u+1)}$ and  $u\rightarrow 0$ with  L'Hospitals rule we can easily see $\lim \frac{u}{ln(u+1)}\rightarrow1$

Comment: what about uniform convergence . This only gives us the pointwise limit right?

Comment: ah yes right i totally forgot about this , we can see that $f_{n+1}\leq f_{n}$ and $\left [ 0,1 \right ]$ is compact so from   Dini's criterion we have the uniform convergence

Comment: Ya ok thanks!!!